# Adding a new tab, I have no idea how

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, tabs

I am using XCode 4.3 and I am creating a tab bar application following an example in my book (likely used for XCode version < 4.3).

By default the newly created tab-bar application includes 2 tabs. you can see my screenshot

[image]
And now I would like to add another tab (the TabExampleThirdViewControler as you also see in the image). But I don't know how to make it the third tab. My old book says that I need to link it to the MainWindow but as you see in the image, there is no MainWindow file at all.

This sort of update from new version of XCode pretty confuses a beginner like me. Thank you for any guidance you could offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what approach you are follwoing to create tabs. But look at mine. I always create tabs like this. This is very easy to implement :

```
Appdelegate.h

UITabBarController *tabBarController;
// set properties

Appdelegate.m

// Synthesize

tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.delegate=self;

// Adding Search,Nearby,Map,AboutUs,Favorites Tabs to tabBarController  
Search * search = [[Search alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *searchNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]        initWithRootViewController:search];  

Nearby* nearby = [[Nearby alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *nearbyNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nearby];  

Map* map = [[Map alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *mapNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:map];  

AboutUs* aboutUs = [[AboutUs alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *aboutUsNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aboutUs];  

Favorites* favorites = [[Favorites alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *favoritesNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:favorites];  

NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:searchNav,nearbyNav,mapNav,aboutUsNav,favoritesNav, nil];  
tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers; 

[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

Then in each of the view controllers mentioned above you need to implement

```
- (id)init {}
```

in which you can set Tab name and image.

I always follow this approach and it never fails. The tabs are always visible.